# Pandas reversing the orders of the rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hello I am working with a very large csv data frame with pandas how would I reverse a list within it? The code below when run assigns `row:0 = 15710.01` and `row:1862 = 243.95` I want to reverse the code so that `row:1862 = 15710.01` and `row:0 = 243.95`.
Code:

```
import pandas as pd
data =pd.read_csv('input.csv')
PC_close =data['Close']
PC_close
```

Output of the current code

```
0       15710.01
1       15710.87
2       15318.00
3       15348.20
4       15484.55
          ...   
1858      247.60
1859      249.50
1860      246.30
1861      245.39
1862      243.95
Name: Close, Length: 1863, dtype: float64
```

Comment: There's a typo in your question, please clarify what the output of the expected code is.

Comment: Could you please clarify the typo

Comment: "The code below when run assigns row:0 = 15710.01 and row:1862 = 15710.01" but the data indicates something else. And the expected output is " I want to reverse the code so that row:0 = 15710.01 and row:1862 = 243.95" but that's exactly what the "current code" is showing below. Please clarify what is your current and expected result. Thanks.

Comment: Oh my bad sorry about that read it a few times but must have missed it. It should be all good now

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. Please check the answer below. Thanks

Comment: Bump pl let us know how your solution hunting went. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reverse the values without reversing the index, you can use

```
df[::-1].set_index(df.index)
```

**MinRepex**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
print (df)

   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

df2 = df[::-1].set_index(df.index)
print (df2)

   a  b
0  3  6
1  2  5
2  1  4
```

---

Another method that works well if you have many rows is in-place re-assignment. This is generally faster but involves working with numpy directly (NumPandas).

```
df[:] = df[::-1].to_numpy()  # modifies the original frame
# or 
# df[:] = df.to_numpy()[::-1]  # slightly faster  
print (df)  

   a  b
0  3  6
1  2  5
2  1  4
```